# jQuery for force triggering onChange of select dropdown

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, drop-down-menu, onchange

I want to trigger the onChange event of a select dropdown using jQuery. I have wired up the function with the onChange event by using : `$(element2).change(populateRelatedDropdowns);` It's working fine when I am manually changing the values of the select control. But when I want to trigger the onChange by using : `$(entydd).trigger('change');` it simply doesn't work.

Please assist me. Thanks.

Code for wiring up the event with select dropdown :

```
var element2 = document.createElement("select");
$(element2).change(populateAttrsDropdowns);


function populateAttrsDropdowns() 
{
//does something
}
```

Upto this is smooth. Works when I change the dropdown values manually.

Now I have a requirement when I have manually set the option value for the dropdown and want the onChange even to be triggered. Code below(**in a different function**) :

```
for (i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) 
{
    $('#btnAdd').trigger('click');
    var entydd = (i+1) + ".enty"; //this is the name of my dropdowns..there are a couple
    document.getElementById(entydd).value = customArray[i].custom_value;
    $(entydd).trigger('change');
}
```

Hope this extra code portion helps.

Comment: please show the code that is giving you issues in its context.

Comment: `$(element2).trigger('change');` not `$(entydd).trigger('change');`

Comment: The code is too huge to paste here. I am editing my first post to include as much relevant code as possible.

Comment: @mgraph : entydd is what I am using in a different function. It refers to the same select dropdown.

Comment: If entydd reprents a select then to change the value you should use document.getElementById(entydd).options[i].value='some value', the select itself has no value property. To change the index you should use selectedIndex.

Comment: @sheikh : By using this code :  `document.getElementById(entydd).value = customArray[i].custom_value;` I am selecting the required value of the select dropdown. The problem is not there. The problem is I am not able to force trigger the onClick of the select dropdown.

Comment: @Heera: what you are suggesting is changing the value of the option ittself, not the value of the select, which is its selected element. and, you should be using jQuery to do it: $("#select").val("optVal");, or what you are saying $('#select:nth-child(i)').val('newOptVal');

Comment: Take a look at my answer, may be that is the point.

Comment: Have you checked what your entydd contains ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera : Yes, it contains the id of the required select dropdown. I have debugged the script.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be

```
$('#'+entydd).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Whatever your error is but you have to use $('#'+entydd). To select an element by id using jquery you must use the #. In your code var entydd = (i+1) + ".enty" there is no hash with id.

Comment: Try to log console.log($('#'+entydd)) and see if it returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

try to rewrite this:

```
for (i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) 
{
    var mySelect = $((i+1) + ".enty");
    var myVal = customArray[i].custom_value;
    mySelect.val(myVal);
}
```

i haven't tested it, but that (setting the value on the select), just might trigger the change event, if you do it via jquery, as opposed to pure js.

and if it doesn't trigger the change, you can add a second call: myChanged(mySelect,myVal)

Comment: As far as I know, `.val()` doesn't trigger the change evenet. Also `.val()` doesn't seem to work with my code, which is why I went with the `document.getElementById().value=myvalue` thing as depicted in my code.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Sorry, I added the link. You copy your relevant html to the top left, your javascript to the bottom left, then you choose jquery in the select on the very left and then you can save it and post the link here. make sure, you just include the code that is giving you trouble. often times, creating the fiddle alone will help you solve it...